# For each problem / PHP Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

I have been battling with this code for quite a while and just don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Have tried quite a few variants of the configuration but to no avail. The most confusing part is that it works absolutely fine for displaying a product catalogue (with different variables) but just not this!

errors are:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: quotes in C:\wamp\www\longlifedecking\quote.php on line 40 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0089  689992  {main}( )   ..\quote.php:0

( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\longlifedecking\quote.php on line 40 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0089  689992  {main}( )   ..\quote.php:0
```

and the code which I have combined is:

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php'; ?>


<?php include 'inc/dbconnect.php'; ?>  


<?php
// Quotes link from Nav

$sessionProdId = $_SESSION["cart"];


$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_text FROM products WHERE prod_id ='$sessionProdId'");
if (!$result)
{
$error = 'Error fetching products: ' . mysqli_error($link);
include 'error.php';
exit();
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$quotes[] = array('id' => $row['prod_id'], 'name' => $row['prod_name'], 'text' => $row['prod_text']);
}

?>


    <section id="ctrCol" class="fl">
      <section class="partFill lrgMod ctr">
        <header>
          <h1>Quote me</h1>
        </header>
        <p>Your shopping cart contains <?php echo count($_SESSION['cart']); ?> items.</p>

        <?php  Print_r ($_SESSION); ?> 

        <div class="partFill">
          <ul>

          <?php foreach ($quotes as $quote): ?>
            <li>
              <h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($quote['name'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></h3>
              <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($quote['text'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></p>
             </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </section>
    </section> <!-- end of ctrCol -->
<?php include 'inc/rightnav.php'; ?>   
<?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

My apologies if this post isn't formatted correctly but this is my first post and just getting used to it!

Many thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the problem sorted. The issue was that no value was being passed to the variable for the MySQL query.

I was not using the session's array properly. To use the ID's held within the session I had to 
implode the array.

```
$sessionProdId = implode(",",$_SESSION['cart']); 

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_text FROM products WHERE prod_id IN ($sessionProdId)");
```

This then allows the output to function correctly with the previous code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to initialize `$quotes` before you begin using it, so it exists if your query doesn't return any rows:

```
$quotes = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $quotes[] = array('id' => $row['prod_id'], 'name' => $row['prod_name'], 'text' => $row['prod_text']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never defined $quotes outside of the `while()` loop. If the query returns no rows, then $quotes will not be defined, and the foreach loop will fail. As well, since it's not defined outside the loop, you've not told PHP that it's an array, so it's warning you.

Simply adding

```
 $quotes = array();
```

immediately outside the `while(fetch...)` loop should solve the problem.

Comment: Lots of correct answers, but I've only up-voted this one, because it gives by far the clearest explanation to what is happening, why it's triggering warnings and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Near as I can tell, the only reason would be if there were no results from the db query, so $quotes is never set with anything.  But overall, it's just a notice, no big deal.  You can get rid of it by declaring your $quotes as an array, before the while loop.

```
$quotes = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning that you are yousing a variable that's not declared.

You could start with

```
 quote = array();
```

to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty self-explanatory: Place `$quotes = array();` just before your `while` statement and both issues should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have a mysql error, or the result to the query is empty. Because of that, the quotes array is never initialized.

Comment: Perfect. Stupidly I did not check the WHERE portion of the MySQL query which doesn't seem to be working. Its now an entirely new, session related problem!

Answer (score 1):

for wahtever reason, you are not pulling any results.
2 ways to fix.
1.) suppress the error..  `<?php foreach ((array)$quotes as $quote): ?>`
2.) initialize $quotes as an array to start with `$quotes=arrray();`

Comment: option (1) will only solve one of the two warnings. To get rid of them both, go with option (2).